# Dein Server läuft mit der PHP-Version 4.4.9, aber WordPress 3.9.1 benötigt mindestens die Version 5.2.4

Tags: php, wordpress

The php version for the wordpress installation is wrong on the server (web.de).
At the provider (web.de) i can't find any possibility to change the php version.

Comment: You are probably the most awkward person on the internet. PHP 4.4 in the year 2014, really dude ? This version is 10+ years old.

Comment: Contact web.de. We're not web.de support. They *gotta* offer a version newer than 4.4.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because we can't provide support for a provider.

Comment: You should definitely contact your provider and see what their support will suggest and can do for resolving the issue.

Comment: strange that nobody complained about the german title....so I have to do this: ENGLISH ONLY!!!

Comment: @FlorianGl: With one exception, all users who commented or answered here are German as well :-P

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that by default, web.de uses PHP4 to interpret .php files. PHP5 is installed, you can try by adding three files:

- `test.php5` with content `<?php phpinfo() ?>`
- `test.php4` with content `<?php phpinfo() ?>`
- `test.php` with content `<?php phpinfo() ?>`

Calling them all from your browser, you will find out that .php and .php4 are interpreted using php 4, while .php5 is interpreted using php 5!

You can change this behaviour by adding a .htaccess file to your wordpress directory with the following content:

```
Type application/x-httpd-php5 .php
```

Comment: Btw.: Is there a special badge for correctly answering a question that has 5 or more downvotes? ;)

Comment: With a tiny (or, large) bit of luck you may get http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/95/reversal ;)